# python - open file in application

Tags: python-2.7, terminal, popen, quicktime

I am using terminal to sucsessfully open a file in quicktime player 7, but can't seem to get it working using python to do the same thing.
So this is working from terminal:

```
open -a "Quicktime Player 7" /Users/Me/Movies/test.mov
```

But this is not working in python 2.7, it opens quicktime, but not the file:

```
command = ('open -a "Quicktime Player 7"', 'Users/Me/Movies/test.mov')
subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass `command` as `list`/`tuple`, you have to split the arguments up correctly:

```
command = ('open', '-a', 'Quicktime Player 7', '/Users/Me/Movies/test.mov')
subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True)
```

Then I think you should also be able to drop the `shell=True` parameter. Further, you could look into [`subprocess.call()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) or [`subprocess.check_call()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call) (the former returns the return value of the program, the latter raises an exception if the return value indicates an error):

```
subprocess.check_call(['open', '-a', 'Quicktime Player 7', '/Users/Me/Movies/test.mov'])
```

NB: Coding-style-wise, `command` is usually passed as list, as seen in the docs I linked above.

**Edit:** Add `'/'` at the beginning of both paths to make it work.

Comment: the first suggestion does nothing, just runs wand nothing happens, the subprocess.check_call gives returned non-zero exit status 1.

Comment: Which operating system are you running?

Comment: subprocess.check_call now works, I had to add a / to the beginning of the file path.